# Clearing $this->input->post()?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do we clear/reset `$this->input->post()`?  Probably something analogous to clearing `$_POST` ?

Answer (score 1):

To clear the post use

```
unset ($_POST);
```

Comment: doesn’t work when using set_value('form_field_name') in view file. Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

if it is a must;

create two copies of forms(preferebly in two files in view();

1) every form of type

> echo form_input('username','','placeholder="username"')."";
>   let it be `main_form.php`;

2) every form of type

> echo form_input('username', set_value('username','username'))."";
>   let it be `sub_form.php`;

redirect all repeated request to second page

whenever you donot want POST values, then call `main_form()`

[there might be other ways].

Answer (score 0):

From the page point of view is better to use ajax-request or after a sucesfully form post to redirect to the same page, so if the user refreshes the page will NOT post the form again.

I think something like this `redirect(current_url());` (not sure).

This will clear your post and ensure that user don't accidentally double post the data.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the CI form_validation method.

$this->form_validation->clear_field_data();